# Using requestAnimationFrame in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to implement infinite scroll in angular2 which

1. automatically removes DOM which are out of viewport.
2. uses requestAnimationFrame instead onscroll.

I noticed above was implemented using Mithriljs which is available in below link. I am confused on how to use requestAnimationFrame  and build a class called ScrollListener in angular2. Please suggest?

https://github.com/flarum/core/blob/master/js/lib/utils/ScrollListener.js

https://github.com/flarum/core/blob/master/js/forum/src/components/PostStream.js

**PS:** Sorry for my English. I am not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what information you need exactly

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3c8fa8c50d820e3317bc40292c73df03c8b23e86/modules/angular2/src/animate/browser_details.ts#L40) is an example

```ts
class RafQueue {
  currentFrameId: number;
  constructor(public callback: Function, public frames: number) { this._raf(); }
  private _raf() {
    this.currentFrameId = DOM.requestAnimationFrame(timestamp => this._nextFrame(timestamp));
  }
  private _nextFrame(timestamp: number) {
    this.frames--;
    if (this.frames > 0) {
      this._raf();
    } else {
      this.callback(timestamp);
    }
  }
  cancel() {
    DOM.cancelAnimationFrame(this.currentFrameId);
    this.currentFrameId = null;
  }
}
```

but I run into https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6904 recently (not checked since if it's working again)

Comment: Thanks. This still not working. But now i understand, how to use requestAnimationFrame and callback in angular2. I now created similar function to listen the scroll. This link has more information on this. http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to call RequestAnimationFrame(RAf):

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('element available::' + this.desiredElmentAvailable);
    if(this.desiredElmentAvailable)
    window.requestAnimationFrame( () => this.onRenderComplete.emit(true));

    }
  }
```

---

Here `this.desiredElmentAvailable` is a domElement that is present in the View.
And when the rendering is complete an event is emitted and perform whatever you want to do as a part of it.

Answer (score -2):

I found a solution:

Add this to your index.html!

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.17/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

After that everything works!